# Convert SQL datetime to specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table with one `datetime` colomn as below:

**tbTest**

```
ID          int  
SetDate  datetime
```

and one entry like:

```
ID      SetDate
1    04/10/2014 2:38:16 PM
```

I want to convert SetDate to `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss PM` or  `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm PM`

Desired Output:

```
ID      SetDate
1    10-04-2014 2:38:16 PM
```

or

```
1    10-04-2014 2:38 PM
```

Comment: and what did you find when you searched?

Comment: `@Mitch Wheat' i have tried to convert date using this site link `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp`.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `convert`

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) + ' ' + 
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 100), 14, 4)+ ' ' +
       RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 2)
```

Comment: No space between time and am/pm as desired.

Comment: thanks for correction. i've modified the query and add the space

Comment: I don't want to be pedantic but OP wanted `4:06:06 PM` instead of `16:06:06 PM` so 12h time. An AM/PM designator in 24h format is pointless, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use sql convert method  for getting Desired output :-23-04-2014 10:16 AM

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 105) + ' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,getDate(),100),7)),7),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to answer, but it is worth pointing out to the OP that the three digit numbers in the `CONVERT` are date styles which are listed [here in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), seeing as all three answers so far have made use of differing style modifiers.

Comment: Output for me: 10/04/2014 14:38:16, so neither `-` nor am/pm designator

Comment: use should use 105 instead of 103 if you want output in the form of dd-mm-yyyy else remains same.  and thanks @StevePettifer for encouraging me

Comment: Still: `22-04-2014 15:48:55` (f.e. in germany), i thought OP wants the AM/PM designator  as: `10-04-2014 2:38 PM`

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR(100), getdate(), 106), ' ', '-')
+' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(GETDATE()AS Time), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with the appropriate styles:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), @SetDate, 110) 
    + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(19), @SetDate, 100), 14, 4)
    + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(19), @SetDate, 100), 18, 2)
```

The first is for the date part, the second for the 12h time part and the last for the am/pm designator.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33139/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and best looking query you can use is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SetDate, 105) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(SetDate AS TIME), 100)
```

Output:

```
31-07-2001 12:00AM
```

No string manipulation required.

Another example:

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
SET @Date = '2014-31-12 18:00:00'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date, 105) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(@Date AS TIME), 100) AS FormatDate
```

Outputs:

```
31-12-2014 6:00PM
```